# How do I write this equation in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

[image: Cardano Triplets]

I really don't know how to write this correctly. This is how I tried:

```
def is_cardano_triplet(a, b, c):
    f = lambda x: x ** 1. / 2
    g = lambda x: x ** 1. / 3
    return g(a + b*f(c)) + g(a - b*f(c)) == 1

print is_cardano_triplet(2,1,5) # I should get True
```

I should get `True` for `2, 1, 5`, but I'm not. What's wrong with my function?

Comment: Take a look at [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: There is a `math.sqrt` or `math.pow` function, you don't need to implement your own.

Comment: You'll need to reformulate your equation to work purely in terms of integers, or perhaps bring in a sufficiently powerful symbolic math library. (Also, `x ** 1. / 2` is `(x ** 1.) / 2`, not `x ** (1. / 2)`.)

Comment: Python follows [BEDMAS](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/brit1.html) and as user2357112 has pointed out, you are not raising your numbers to a fractional power unless you implement brackets.

Comment: just found this, can help you: https://github.com/abusayeedomar/cardano-triplets-solution/blob/master/triplets.py

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Well, a program is meant to be heavily involved. It's just that you can't simply transcribe the formula for what you're supposed to calculate and expect the result to be a correct, efficient program. You need to apply some math and find a good algorithm.

Comment: @user2357112 the more I browse Project Euler, the more I convince myself about this, I see what you mean!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing a few calculations, [I found out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((a%2Bbsqrt(c))%5E(1%2F3))+%2B+((a-bsqrt(c))%5E(1%2F3))+%3D+1) that:

[image: lolz]

and therefore:

[image: lolzz]

Now, due to floating point arithmetic being imprecise on binary-based systems for [known reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), the first formula is pretty hard to compute precisely. However, **the second one is much easier to compute** without floating point precision errors since that it doesn't involve irrational functions and `a`, `b` and `c` are integers.

Here's the smart solution:

```
def is_cardano_triplet(a, b, c):
    return (a + 1)**2 * (8*a - 1) - 27*b**2*c == 0

>>> is_cardano_triplet(2, 1, 5)
True
```

Comment: Of course, to solve the Project Euler problem, generating triplets and *testing* whether they're Cardano triplets would still be unworkably inefficient. You might try iterating over possible values of `(a + 1) / 3` (as `a` must be congruent to 2 mod 3) and considering factors of `(a + 1) / 3` and square factors of `(8*a - 1) / 3` to generate valid `b` values, from which the corresponding `c` immediately follows.

Answer (score 1):

The power operator (`**`) has a higher priority than the division one (`/`). So you need to set parentheses:

```
f = lambda x: x ** (1./3)
```

Still, floating point operations are not exact, so you have to compare with some small uncertainty:

```
def is_cardano_triplet(a, b, c):
    f = lambda x: x ** (1. / 2)
    g = lambda x: x ** (1. / 3)
    return abs(g(a + b*f(c)) + g(a - b*f(c)) - 1) < 1e-10
```

Now you get the problem, that negative numbers are only allowed for roots of odd numbers, but floating points aren't exact, so you have to handle negative numbers by hand:

```
def is_cardano_triplet(a, b, c):
    f = lambda x: x ** (1. / 2)
    g = lambda x: (-1 if x<0 else 1) * abs(x) ** (1. / 3)
    return abs(g(a + b*f(c)) + g(a - b*f(c)) - 1) < 1e-10
```

Now

```
print is_cardano_triplet(2,1,5)
```

results in `True`.

Comment: while this is part of it, the function still returns False because of floating point rounding, see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: `print is_cardano_triplet(2,1,5)` gives: `ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power` for me.

Comment: Comparing with a tolerance will just produce *different* wrong results. You'll get false positives for inputs that aren't Cardano triplets.